# need to fix ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, python-3.x, valueerror

Hi I keep getting this error when I run this function in my main code. It's supposed to take the row and columns that have a @ as a value and dump them into a file. I keep getting the error: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

```
def savePattern(Gen):
    file = open("SavedFile.txt", "r+")
    file.truncate(0)
    file.close()
    print("Pattern has been saved in SavedFile.txt!")
    for row, index in enumerate(Gen):
        for col, indices in enumerate(index):
            if "@" in indices:
                import sys
                sys.stdout = open("SavedFile.txt", "a")
                print(row, col)
                sys.stdout.close()
```

Any suggestion on how to fix this helps. Thanks

Comment: Is `Gen` csv data?

Comment: What line are you getting the `ValueError` on?

Comment: The second time this function runs, it tries to do a `print()`, but it can't because `sys.stdout` was closed at the end of the first run.

Comment: In general if you want to write the output to a file consider using a redirection: `python your_script.py > your_output_file.txt`. If you need console output as well write it to `stderr`.